# Displaying .dcm files with XTK's X.volume()

Tags: javascript, dicom, xtk

According to the [lesson 15](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/xtk/lessons/tree/gh-pages/15/#run) I pass `.dcm` file to the `volume`. I get no errors (e.g. no parsing errors I faced before) but nothing is displayed. What could be wrong with the `.dcm` files?

Here is a excerpt of the code I use:

```
function demo(file){  
  var _dicom = [file];
  var r = new X.renderer3D();
  r.init();

  var v = new X.volume();
  v.file = _dicom.map(function(v) {
    return file;    
  });

  r.add(v);

  r.render();

  r.onShowtime = function() {
    v.volumeRendering = true;
  };

};
```

I pass the full file path here. Well, I'm not sure it's a correct wording, but I'd lile to know, what dicom settings or parameters could cause such a behaviour, no errors and no diplayed data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to drag the .dcm file into http://slicedrop.com and see the same effect? DICOM support currently only exists for uncompressed DICOM files and we didn't get Ultrasound too work yet. So on uncompressed MR data or CT data in DICOM it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed, it didn't work on that site. Is there a resource related to your project that is made for such discussions? Cuz, well, I don't think someone else on SO would answer possible future questions.

Comment: I think Stack Overflow is the right place for that. I do think that other users could benefit. Can you share one of your .dcm files so we can track the error down?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I can share it. Also, it wasn't probably an error, just compressed files, and conversion to other supported formats worked like a charm.